# Is it time to rethink the rules regarding duplicate/signpost questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, user-incentives, signpost-questions

After receiving such a warm reception from my [Cooperative, democratic, topic-scoped curation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417648/2943403) proposal, I decided to continue my crusade to find all of the signposts and related pages for the task of "transposing an array with PHP".

This isn't even a common question/topic -- most new programmers don't even know what "transposing" means.  Even still, I was surprised by how much redundancy there was.

As I searched, I took it upon myself to up/downvote posts, edit, answer, vote to close/reopen, comment, and delete with the intent to improve the researcher experience.  And yet, I am still concerned that researchers will get lost in the sea of redundancy.  Maybe I'm wrong.  So now I'd like to ask...

How many signposts does one narrow technique/topic need on Stack Overflow?

If the response to that question is "as many as possible", then this effectively says that posting duplicate questions is a good thing (regardless of the vote score of the question).

If posting duplicate questions is a good thing, then why do we question ban users for asking too many duplicate questions?

Why do we block new answers after a duplicate question is closed? If we do not want answers on duplicate questions, then why do we allow answerers to be rewarded with rep points?  If answers must not be added after the closure, then why is it okay to add answers before the closure?

I find all this dissonance to be maddening.  Is it time for a rethink of the rules?  As things are now, I am considering hanging up my hammer and just answering every dupe -- because the system design incentivizes me to do so.

Folks asked me for context on my previous question, so below is my current list of transposition questions.

1. 2009 [Transposing multidimensional arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/797251/2943403) -- 50K views
2. 2009 [Joining Arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1962933/2943403) -- 150 views
3. 2010 [Is there better way to transpose a PHP 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3460022/2943403) -- 5K views
4. 2010 [Combine 3 or more arrays (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3488746/2943403) -- 4K views
5. 2010 [Can I convert individual fields of a 'mysql_query' to arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4149244/2943403) -- 500 views
6. 2011 [Combine arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6308277/2943403) 300 views
7. 2011 [PHP: Take several arrays, and make new ones based on shared indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7404125/2943403) -- 100 views
8. 2011 [Insert Multiple rows using implode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7679471/2943403) -- 3K views
9. 2011 [how convert the element structure of an array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6789759/2943403) -- 100 views
10. 2011 [php reassign array contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7074080/2943403) -- 150 views
11. 2012 [PHP Grouping Array by Index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11448084/2943403) -- 1K views
12. 2012 [displaying a mysql table vertically - for comparison or for print out purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10546117/2943403) -- 4K views
13. 2012 [Elegant way to convert associative array into an indexed one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10499805/2943403) -- 3K views
14. 2012 [PHP Grouping Array by Index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11448084/2943403) -- 1K views
15. 2012 [Order in loops foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11003149/2943403) -- 350 views
16. 2012 [PHP Array, Move Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11085890/2943403) -- 100 views
17. 2013 [Refactor (transpose) array to unique keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19697343/2943403) -- 200 views
18. 2013 [How to merge 3 arrays into one big array (same keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15223428/2943403) -- 200 views
19. 2013 [Smarty/PHP - How to match up keys between 3 different arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18280370/2943403) -- 750 views
20. 2013 [PHP rotate matrix counter-clockwise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16997580/2943403) -- 3K views
21. 2013 [loop to populate html table vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17608513/2943403) -- 9K views
22. 2013 [How to merge 3 arrays into one big array (same keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15223428/2943403) -- 200 views
23. 2014 [PHP looping array to get combined rows of items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22757123/2943403) -- 50 views
24. 2014 [MYSQL / Query Builder / Eloquent - Transpose rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27348304/2943403) -- 1k views
25. 2014 [Change several ARRAY into new ARRAYS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23380098/2943403) -- 50 views
26. 2014 [array merge issue in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22359994/2943403) -- 50 views
27. 2014 [How to combine associative array by indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23276410/2943403) -- 450 views
28. 2014 [PHP: Grouping array values by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21512889/2943403) -- 150 views
29. 2014 [How to transpose two arrays to form an indexed array of associative arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27380756/2943403) -- 100 views
30. 2014 [PHP - multidimensional array from arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22716381/2943403) -- 100 views
31. 2014 [Display transposed data as html table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26851295/2943403) -- 100 views
32. 2015 [I have 5 arrays each array contains 10 values, I want to invert these arrays into 10 arrays and each array contains 5 values using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33996371/2943403) -- 6K views
33. 2015 [create transpose matrix using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30082814/2943403) -- 6K views
34. 2015 [Why does array_map() with null as callback create an "array of arrays"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31592503/2943403) -- 2K views
35. 2015 [Chunk and transpose a flat array into rows with a specific number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31740439/2943403) -- 50 views
36. 2015 [Merge 2 arrays into 1 multidimensional array by index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29635580/2943403) -- 800 views
37. 2015 [Merging two simple arrays into a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28086716/2943403) -- 50 views
38. 2015 [Populating HTML table with multidimensional array vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31620129/2943403) -- 1K views
39. 2015 [Merge multidimensional array preserving keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28211456/2943403) -- 100 views
40. 2015 [Transpose csv file data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31485403/2943403) -- 300 views
41. 2016 [Multi dimensional loops from 4 existing arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36460680/2943403) -- 50 views
42. 2016 [How to use an array of arrays with array_map(...) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39599649/2943403) -- 2K views
43. 2016 [How can I combine arrays in one multidimensional array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983828/2943403) -- 50 views
44. 2016 [PHP array, move keys and values to new array, but mix it up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37219316/2943403) -- 50 views
45. 2016 [How to transpose array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36493112/2943403) -- 900 views
46. 2016 [Hierarchical Array Conversion to Flat Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37756023/2943403) -- 300 views
47. 2016 [merge and reorder 3 arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36777297/2943403) -- 50 views
48. 2016 [Insert database rows from columns of data from associative array of indexed arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37669673/2943403) -- 50 views
49. 2017 [Transpose rows and columns in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47718625/2943403) -- 5K views
50. 2017 [php reformat array representation from html form array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43490218/2943403) -- 50 views
51. 2017 [How to insert arrays into a main array in PHP to make it 2d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44963356/2943403) -- 50 views
52. 2017 [How can I combine array's items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44493581/2943403) -- 250 views
53. 2017 [Restructure multidimensional array of column data into multidimensional array of row data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43948739/2943403) -- 1K views
54. 2017 [Transpose associative array of associative arrays to create associative array of indexed arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41974671/2943403) -- 4K views
55. 2017 [Merging PHP array to multidimensional array from another array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46809764/2943403) -- 50 views
56. 2018 [Combine items of two array and create new array using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52848710/2943403) -- 50 views
57. 2018 [How to collect 3 arrays in 1 array using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53467626/2943403) -- 50 views
58. 2018 [How do I use array_map recursively in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52938819/2943403) -- 1K views
59. 2018 [Laravel loop through set of input arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50541446/2943403) -- 150 views
60. 2018 [Foreach to combine to array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51482052/2943403) -- 50 views
61. 2019 [php extract associate arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58018999/2943403) -- 50 views
62. 2019 [How to combine and transpose 2 PHP arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52299950/2943403) -- 50 views
63. 2019 [How to merge two arrays into one without iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54290931/2943403) -- 100 views
64. 2019 [How to create an associative array from two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55022287/2943403) -- 3K views
65. 2019 [how to get each column of values as array directly, and without using pluck laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58340942/2943403) -- 650 views
66. 2019 [Combine (merge) 2 arrays by keys and change keys name in the result array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54902146/2943403) -- 800 views
67. 2019 [Array_map and array_combine for more than two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54049590/2943403) -- 500 views
68. 2019 [Merge values from different arrays to one with the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54098206/2943403) -- 100 views
69. 2019 [Native PHP function that pairs elements from arbitrary number of input arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54098839/2943403) -- 50 views
70. 2019 [Transpose multidimensional array and join values with commas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56670363/2943403) -- 50 views
71. 2019 [How to create 3 arrays from 1 multidimensional array with 2 arrays inside](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57763935/2943403) -- 50 views
72. 2019 [How to store 3 key by index per row PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59139776/2943403) -- 50 views
73. 2019 [How to change associative array value in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55238891/2943403) -- 400 views
74. 2019 [How to put array inside array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58476172/2943403) -- 50 views
75. 2019 [How to Loop through multi dimensional array of $_FILES array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55087443/2943403) -- 200 views
76. 2019 [How to change associative array value in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55238891/2943403) -- 400 views
77. 2019 [PHP multi-dimensional array, merge duplicate keys into new arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58555967/2943403) -- 50 views
78. 2020 [Transpose of column to row in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65487428/2943403) -- 50 views
79. 2020 [combine and merge array in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64058699/2943403) -- 100 views
80. 2021 [how to import a transposed excel in Laravel using laravel-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68260454/2943403) -- 450 views
81. 2021 [Transpose imported Excel with Matrix table to Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69829757/2943403) -- 50 views
82. 2021 [Group multi array by key and value PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66344313/2943403) -- 50 views
83. 2021 [Create a multidimensional array based on number of values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68952580/2943403) -- 50 views
84. 2022 [Rotate a Collection in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71525364/2943403) -- 50 views
85. 2022 [Zip multiple arrays in PHP based on their identical keys and not their indices or their positions in array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71035858/2943403) -- 50 views
86. 2022 [Convert nested associative array to single array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71963838/2943403) -- 50 views

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Comment: *"why do we question ban users for asking too many duplicate questions"* ... that's not the issue, the issue is asking bad questions. If they are dupe or not doesn't matter as long as they are positively received. And I might have a pessimistic view on this, but I guess wasting time on this isn't worth it. "quality" (like good signposts) is a battle you can't win (anymore). There are way too many posts coming in and way to few users doing housekeeping chores like voting, editing, reviewing, etc. And you have users who prefer quantity over quality working against you as well.

Comment: 2020 seems to have been a good year. Only two questions in this list from that year.

Comment: Also I think this is by now the standard for many other popular problems as well. People don't do research on the one hand and others like to answer rather than close. Nobody likes to search really.

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes find myself writing comments with tags in them, like
[transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transpose), that say something like this:

> FYI your task is often called taking the [transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transpose) of your array.

And I often edit a question's tags in the hopes of making the question more visible to other answerers.

It's a little less work for me than trying to hunt up the canonical answer to close something as a dup. And it, I think, contributes more to the questioner's learning than just duphammering the question: they get a chance to refactor their formulation of their question instead of just getting a smack.

These little breadcrumbs (they hardly qualify as signposts) sometimes help a questioner who says they've googled with no joy. Knowing what something is called in the trade-specific jargon is often what a questioner needs.

Obviously closing a question as a dup is still the right move in many circumstances.

Maybe making a tag edit more visible to the questioner would help this learning process without needing a global rework of the signpost question weltanschauung.

I agree that the php transpose q&a is, umm, a bit over the top.

Comment: "they get a chance to refactor their formulation of their question" Is that actually a good thing? If they remove their "wrong" description, that means others with the same vocabulary won't find the question.